# Return row based on maximum value in single field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has multiple rows of similar data as per below:

| Name | Version | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | 1 | Blue |
| James | 2 | Blue |
| James | 3 | Black |
| Jill | 1 | Red |
| Jill | 2 | Blue |
| Jill | 3 | Red |
| Jill | 4 | Black |
| Jill | 5 | Red |
| Steve | 1 | Blue |
| Steve | 2 | Blue |

I want to be able to run a query that returns only the rows with the maximum Version # and grouped by Name. Regardless of what the Colour is.

So the result of the query will look like this:

| Name | Version | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | 3 | Black |
| Jill | 5 | Red |
| Steve | 2 | Blue |

Thanks

I tried this

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Version), Colour
FROM DB
GROUP BY Name
```

But its says Colour needs to be in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. When I put it in the GROUP BY clause it returns rows with all the different colours and not just the MAX version #.

Comment: If you provide DDL+DML (Or a DBFiddle) you make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: so, you are correct, remove COLOR from select statement as you stated: [ Regardless of what the Colour is.]

Answer (score 0):

use `PARTITION BY` clause.

For each `Name`, sort in descending order by the `Version` column. and use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to assign a unique number (`rn`) to the rows within each group.
The most recent Version will have an `rn` value of 1.

```
WITH T AS (SELECT
    Name,
    Version,
    Colour,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Version DESC) AS rn
FROM DB)
SELECT
    Name,
    Version,
    Colour
FROM T
WHERE T.rn = 1
```